# Kubuntu 11.10 Lot of Networking problems

Tags: network-manager

Since I upgrade to 11.10 I have a lot of problems with KDE. First of all there are problems in configuring a static IP address. Just to explain @home I have a normal fiber ADSL and I use a DHCP. When I go to a customer I must insert a static IP address. With ifconfig everything seems ok but there is something wrong in searching DNS names. (I have installed Ubuntu and was going ok again). Now I Have reinstalled again Kubuntu 11.10 and I have the same problem in addition today I have discovered that if I connect to a network in another customer office the desktop freezes and I could only switch between windows with alt+tab. No FN key or right click to open run command works. So i unplugged network (configuration is just DHCP here) and tried on another position in office. It was the same. My Laptop freezes when connected, a fedora 14 of a friend works. So I decided to connect my Galaxy S II as USB network device. Everything is ok for like 3 minutes. When I noticed a little loss of signal again the desktop freezes and i must work (like now) just switching between windows with alt+tab). Additional information: Unplugging network or restarting it via Konsole does not not solve the freezing problem. Every time I must open a console and reboot.

Any idea of what tests to do ?

Just a recommendation: If I must post here logs or something else please guide me. I use Linux since Ubuntu 9 but I am not an "expert".

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of networking problems with 11.10 Server. This may help.

First off I had to create `/var/lib/dhcp3` and run `update-rc.d -f apparmor remove`.

Apparmor was configured for use with network manager, which is not even installed on Ubuntu Server 11.10 (or any Ubuntu Server release).

I can't imagine how a missing directory like `/var/lib/dhcp3` passed a smoke test.